# Given $\sum_{k=0}^{n} {n\choose k}= 2^n$, prove that $\sum_{k=0}^{n} k{n\choose k} = n{2}^{n-1}$.

Tags: summation, proof-writing

I'm unsure how to prove this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It was given in the question. I believe it was formatted incorrectly. It should be fine now.

Comment: Hint: For reasonable $k$ we have $k\binom{n}{k}=n\binom{n-1}{k-1}$.

Comment: Vandalism is frowned upon @P.Pally.

Comment: Huh? Why did you edit the question?

Comment: Please do not deface your question. It is not fair to those who have taken the time to give you answers.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**

Use the fundamental relation:
$$\binom nk=\frac nk\binom{n-1}{k-1} \quad\forall k\ge 1.$$

Comment: (+1) nice hint :-) Unfortunately, this question might be on the way to getting closed as off-topic.

Comment: Why off-topic? The O.P. seems not to have any idea on how to proceed and asks for help.

Comment: @Bernard Probably because the OP is trying to cheat on their homework, see vandalism. (I upvoted the answers for the record)

Comment: @Bernard: the question may be a homework question, which seems to be confirmed by the vandalism of the question by the OP. (I was looking at the vote to close.)

Comment: I see. Can't understand such an attitude…

Answer (score 2):

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^nk\binom{n}{k}
&=\sum_{k=1}^nk\binom{n}{k}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^nn\binom{n-1}{k-1}\\
&=n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{k}\\[6pt]
&=n2^{n-1}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Great minds think together!

Comment: Unfortunately, this question looks like an attempt to cheat at homework. As the OP has already seen my answer, I will leave it so that the instructor might also see it.

Answer (score 2):

We have: $(x+1)^n = \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}x^k$. Taking derivative both sides and plug $x = 1$ into the derivative equation to arrive at the answer.